# a Problem about Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, number-theory, open-problem, collatz-conjecture

> Let $a_1$ be an integer. Then we assume
>
> $$
> a_{n+1} =
> \begin{cases}
> 3a_n+1,&\text{$a_n$ is odd}\\
> \frac{a_n}{2},&\text{$a_n$ is even}
> \end{cases}
> $$

Now we prove that

> for any $a_1\in\mathbb N$, there exists $N$ which satisfy: $a_n=1,2$ or $4$,$n\geq{N}$.

At first I want to give it a suitable category for the problem: analysis. And I want to use the basic method: evaluate the upper bound for $a_n$, however I find it's not easy because the iteration is rely on the odd or even property of $a_n$. So I attempt the method of number theory. But I failed to find any way to go over it. Can anyone have idea? Thank you.

Comment: This is a long-standing open problem from number theory, which you are not going to solve with "basic methods". Voting to close.

Comment: @TMM Open problem?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture

Comment: Why downvote? It's a legitimate question and the OP never heard of this Collatz conjecture before.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's false because if $a_n=1$ then $a_{n+1}=4$.

Comment: I'm wrong and fix it

Comment: I realize you answered an early statement of the problem, but it really wasn't so badly stated that we could not interpret it correctly (as the Collatz conjecture), a matter of how $n \ge N$ should be quantified.  If you are posting a one-line Answer, please give the Question the benefit of any doubt.

Comment: Well, I tried in earnest to answer the OP's question and I understand that it's easy to make mistakes; we all do it all the time.  But I'm not telepathic and cannot guess that the OP actually did make a mistake given that I didn't know the Collatz conjecture.  So I'm answering the question as stated.

Comment: But it is an interesting problem!